# Java Pattern to match String beginning and end?

Tags: java, regex

I have an `input` that looks like this : **`0; expires=2016-12-27T16:52:39`**
I am trying extract from this only the date, using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

```
  private String extractDateFromOutput(String result) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(expires=)(.+?)(?=(::)|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("group 1: " + m.group(1));
      System.out.println("group 2: " + m.group(2));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

**Why** does this matcher find more than 1 group ? The output is as follows:

```
group 1: expires=
group 2: 2016-12-27T17:04:39
```

**How can I get only group 2 out of this?**

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean? You yourself defined 3 capturing groups in the pattern. Just use `m.group(2)` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have used more than one capturing group in your regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("expires=(.+?)(?=::|$)");
```

Just remove the capturing group around

1. `expires`
2. `::`

Answer (score 0):

```
private  String extractDateFromOutput(String result) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("expires=(.+?)(?=::|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("group 1: " + m.group(1));
      // no group 2, accessing will gives you an IndexOutOfBoundsException
      //System.out.println("group 2: " + m.group(2));
    }
    return result;
  }
```